# Handling large shapefiles and many features( e.g > 1 million points) in Mapbox and GeoServer

Tags: raster, geoserver, shapefile, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have some issues. But I want to get clarity/assistance on a fundamental one.

I use GeoServer as my tile server to my client using Mapbox GL JS. Now, I have uploaded a shapefile that constitutes almost 1 million points to GeoServer. The points cover a country, like Mexico. Now when I serve this layer through mapbox, and toggle the visibility for viewing, I experience performance issues. Most times, it does not load, and causes the server to stop responding. I know there must be a way to load the tiles that would not impede performance, but I cannot figure out how.
I am concerned because in the future I might be dealing with even bigger files.

TL:DR How do I handle performance issues in Mapbox and GeoServer when I am serving shapefiles, for a region like Africa.

Comment: You should never render 1 million points on screen. If user has 1000x1000 pixels to use for the map it means one point for each pixel on average. What you want to do is to have additional generalized datasets and use them at reasonable scales. Or then you want to cluster close features together.

Comment: Yea. I kinda thought it will not be user friendly. Please can you shed more light on any of the solutions you proffered?

Comment: 1) don't use shapefiles - get PostGIS 2) don't send vector tiles use PNGs instead

Comment: Thanks. 1. I had tried with PostGIS store on Geoserver, and no much difference in performance. 2. I really do not think I can use PNGs. The data has attributes that are useful for interactivity.

Comment: I bet you can use PNGs and filters